# Error with my sqlite with after adding new column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've added "id" to my table and it suddenly stopped working.

The error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.silkamanager, PID: 21747
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.silkamanager/com.example.silkamanager.NowyTrening}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 3 to 1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3446)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7548)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 3 to 1
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:541)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:415)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:341)
        at com.example.silkamanager.SilkaDataBaseHelper.daj3(SilkaDataBaseHelper.java:54)
        at com.example.silkamanager.NowyTrening.onCreate(NowyTrening.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282
```

```
public class NowyTrening extends AppCompatActivity {

    SilkaDataBaseHelper SilkaDataBaseHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nowy_trening);

        TextView kgg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kg1);
        TextView uno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uno1);
        TextView dos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dos1);
        TextView tres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tres1);

        SilkaDataBaseHelper = new SilkaDataBaseHelper(this);
        //SilkaDataBaseHelper.zapis(60,12,11,12);


        //COFANIE NA PASKU AKCJI
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




        cursor = SilkaDataBaseHelper.daj3();



        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int kg = cursor.getInt(0);
            int jed = cursor.getInt(1);
            int dwa = cursor.getInt(2);
            int trz= cursor.getInt(3);

            System.out.println(jed+" "+dwa);

            kgg.setText(String.valueOf(kg));
            uno.setText(String.valueOf(jed));
            dos.setText(String.valueOf(dwa));
            tres.setText(String.valueOf(trz));
            break;

        }



        }

    public void ZapiszOnClick(View view)
    {
        SilkaDataBaseHelper db = new SilkaDataBaseHelper(this);

        EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
        EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e2);
        EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e3);


        String ww1=e1.getText().toString();
        String ww2=e2.getText().toString();
        String ww3=e3.getText().toString();
        int kg;
        System.out.println(ww1);
        int i=Integer.parseInt(ww1);
        Integer w1 = Integer.valueOf(ww1);
        Integer w2 = Integer.valueOf(ww2);
        Integer w3 = Integer.valueOf(ww3);

        db.zapis(60,w1,w2,w3);



    }


    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
        SilkaDataBaseHelper.close();
    }


    //COFANIE NA PASKU AKCJI
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;

    }
}

    lass SilkaDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "silka";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    SilkaDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE WYNIKI (" +
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "KG INTEGER, " +
                "JED INTEGER, " +
                "DWA INTEGER, " +
                "TRZY INTEGER);" + "");
        System.out.println("baza stworzona");
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        System.out.println("ss");
        ;
    }

    //DODAWANIE DO BAZY
    public void zapis(int kg, int l1, int l2, int l3) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues dane = new ContentValues();
        dane.put("KG", kg);
        dane.put("JED", l1);
        dane.put("DWA", l2);
        dane.put("TRZY", l3);

        db.insertOrThrow("WYNIKI", null, dane);
        System.out.println("zapisane" + kg + " " + l1 + " " + l2 + " " + l3);


    }

    public Cursor daj3() {
        String[] kolumny = { "ID","KG", "JED", "DWA", "TRZY"};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        System.out.println("przed");
        Cursor kursor = db.query("WYNIKI", kolumny, null, null, null, null, "ID DESC", "1");
        System.out.println("po");
        return kursor;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing DB_VERSION to 4 in SilkaDataBaseHelper because the error says can not downgrade which means you are creating the version of database which is lower than the previous (means 3)

Comment: Then there is such error:E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ID

Comment: This exception is thrown on the following conditions:

1. The device that you're running the code on has a database file of version 3.
2. The code is requesting version 1 of the database (with a param to SilkaDataBaseHelper constructor)
3. onDowngrade() is not overridden in your code.
Please do check any of the issue is there

Comment: add ID column in the onUpgrade() method using the SQL and change the database version to 4

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE WYNIKI (" +
                "KG INTEGER, " +
                "JED INTEGER, " +
                "DWA INTEGER, " +
                "TRZY INTEGER);" + "");
        System.out.println("baza stworzona");
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE WYNIKI ADD COLUMN ID  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT");
    } Still doesn't work

Comment: did you change the DB_VERSION to 4 along with that??

Comment: Yes i did, still the same

Comment: What is the current database version? Use 
SQLiteDatabase db = new Helper(context).getWritableDatabase();
db.getVersion(); // what value do you get here?
but not in onCreate or onUpgrade

Comment: Can u say exacly what should i do, i tried plenty of options and and still have errors and i cant get it

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the reason of this error...

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall the app on your phone then you compile again. or you can change the version of your database by a higher number

Comment: After this: E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ID
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.silkamanager, PID: 26024
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.silkamanager/com.example.silkamanager.NowyTrening}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ID (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT ID, KG, JED, DWA, TRZY FROM WYNIKI ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3307)